# Formatting date in Web2py Python

Tags: python, database, date, web2py

I'm looking for a function to format a date in order to get day, month and year. Dates are being stored in my database in the following format 2012-09-26.

Comment: So you have YYYY-MM-DD, and what should be the format of your output?

Comment: Do you want to display it in a template or what is the use case?

Comment: Yes, I need to display separate the day, month and year in a template. Thanks for reply!

Comment: Is the date stored as an SQL date type or as a string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your goal is to display on web2py template, so you have to use pure Python to format

```
{{=row.datetime_field.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")}}
```

The above will generate `25/09/2012`

Tale a look at Python strftime documentations.

If you want to show only the day.

```
{{=row.datetime_field.date}}
```

Also you can set it as a representation for that field

```
db.mytable.datetime_field.represent = lambda value, row: value.strftime("format-here")
```

The representation will be useful only on SQLFORM.grid and SQLTABLE

All you need is `strftime`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! This is what Ive been looking for.