# Web2py date format

Tags: web2py

Hello everyone I'm having a problem with this date format for web2py. I just want to show the
month-day-year but I'm getting the year-month-day hour-minute-second. Heres the code that I'm using

```
db.define_table('time',
    Field('date_made', 'datetime', default=request.now))
```

and the given output when I display it is: 2013-1-15 12:24:20
I want the output to look either like 2013-1-15 or 1-15-2103 without the time so I can compare dates.
I already searched on the site and found this [Formatting date in Web2py Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605934/formating-date-in-web2py-python) but don't exactly want to implement it like that because I'm trying to define it in a field

Comment: Why couldn't you just use Field('date_made', 'date')

Answer (score 1):

the correct way to create the input format of a date in web2py is

```
db.define_table('time',
   Field('date_made', 'datetime', default = request.now, requires = IS_DATE(format=('%d-%m-%Y'))) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you ....

```
from datetime import datetime
db.define_table('time',
    Field('date_made', 'datetime', default=lambda:datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
 Field('field_name', 'datetime', default=now)
```

I found [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=vB2-BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA176&lpg=PA176&dq=store%20now%20time%20in%20dal%20web2py%20field&source=bl&ots=6Mjb_AK2go&sig=JroYkjFc0mH3gDZc3eGNIByepBM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibjqq5wsTcAhVMuI8KHYOpCDMQ6AEwBHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=store%20now%20time%20in%20dal%20web2py%20field&f=false) that helped me

Answer (score 0):

import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.today()

Field('date_today','datetime', default=now)

Further reference click [here](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators)

Answer (score -1):

I'm just starting web2py too, so I don't know if this will help. But you can define a format for fields, so maybe doing this will help:

```
Field('date_made', 'datetime', default=request.now, format=('%d-%m-%Y'))
```